# How can I use an old Windows XP hard disk drive and the installed programs installed on it on a modern PC?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, virtual-machine

My father has a 12 yo PC that won’t turn on (I DDXed the problem and it seems to be a faulty motherboard). He uses a very specific program that you can’t get anymore and that works only on XP, but I can’t find new PCs that can run XP anymore (at retailers near me), and my father doesn’t want to waste money on trying to buy parts online to experiment with.

Is there a way to run the Windows XP on the hard disk drive? I thought maybe a virtual machine but I don’t know what specs I’ll need from the new PC (up to $400) or if there are special requirements.

I wish I could just get him a Windows XP PC so he won’t get confused with all the virtual machine aspects since he’s not tech-savvy.

Comment: You might see if VMware Converter will P to V the XP hard drive and then use XP in a virtual machine. Also look hard on eBay for an old PC running XP.

Comment: Windows XP was released in 2001 and runs a lightweight core, theoretically will run in 64 MB RAM. So there are no special requirements you can run it in any old or even newer PCs.

Comment: Nice to see it works as expected! Just a note that you should copy and paste your “UPDATE” into a separate answer. This site is a question and answer site so mixing up your question and answer with an “UPDATE” is not in keeping with the site’s procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what my dad said, apparently the program my dad needed works fine by just copying it’s folder to the same address on the new PC (if it was `C:\x\y` then same on new PC) and running as admin for access rights. All I needed is a desktop to test it so my problem is solved.